# Form class __init__ not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have this form class :

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.notvalidate = kwargs.pop('notvalidate',False)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict,maxlength=75)))
    (...)

    if not notvalidate:        
        def clean_email(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
            if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).count() > 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    _(u"Email already used."))
            return email
```

Although in **init** I set self.notvalidate value to either True(if was given) or False inside the body of MyForm I'm getting `name 'notvalidate' is not defined` (or if I check for self.notvalidate - `name 'self' is not defined`). What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve is changing the class level attribute `clean_email` but you want to do that using instance attribute `self.notvalidate`, so you are doing contradictory things here. Simplest way to not validate would be to check in clean_email and return e.g

```
def clean_email(self):
    if self.notvalidate:
        return

     ....
```

But if due to some **mysterious reason** you do not want clean_mail method to be existing in the class at all, you need to create a class using metaclass or simpler way would be to call a function to create class e.g.

```
def createFormClass(validate):
    class MyClass(object):
        if validate:
            def clean_email(self):
                pass

    return MyClass

MyClassValidated = createFormClass(True)
MyClassNotValidated = createFormClass(False)
```

Though I will strongly suggest NOT to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure why it stated 'is not defined' without this return, but now it works.

Comment: The return has nothing to do with it.  The `self.notvalidate` reference within the instance method `clean_email` is what fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `if not notvalidate` into the `clean_email` method, and reference it using `self.notvalidate`.

```
    def clean_email(self):
       if not self.notvalidate:   
           email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
           if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).count() > 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    _(u"Email already used."))
        return email
```

Also, you may want to rename the flag to `should_validate_email` and lose the negation.

Comment: If you declare it outside it's a class level statement, so you won't have access the instances' `self` property, and thus can't access `self.notvalidate`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `notvalidate` to `self.notvalidate`.